# ¿Cómo funciona el performance en un websocket PHP con conexión a BD?

Tags: php, pdo, websocket

**CONTEXTO.** Tengo el servidor web en una IP y la base de datos (BD) en otro servidor con otra IP. Tengo un websocket PHP (WS) armado con la librería [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). La idea es que el navegador muestre información actualizada segundo a segundo basándose en los datos existentes en la BD. Configuré el WS para que cada segundo el cliente (mediante JS) envíe un mensaje al servidor con el fin de recuperar la data más reciente de la BD y mostrarla en el navegador:

```
let conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
conn.onopen = function (e) {
    setInterval(function () {
        conn.send('enviopeticion');
    }, 1000);
};
```

Todo funciona perfecto en modo desarrollo en local. Pero sospecho que no estoy haciendo bien las cosas y que su paso a producción será un desastre con respecto al performance, justo por lo siguiente.

**PROBLEMA.** Dentro del método onMessage() en el lado del servidor (en mi clase PHP) declaro la nueva conexión a la BD y ejecuto las peticiones a la BD:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $res = array();
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_attrs);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE col=? LIMIT 1');
    if ($stmt->execute([1])) {
        if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $res = array('id'=>$row['id']);
        }
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $pdo = NULL;
    $from->send(json_encode($res));
}
```

Asumo que no debería abrir la conexión a la BD `$pdo = new PDO()` dentro del método onMessage(), porque en ese caso estaría abriendo y cerrando la conexión a BD en cada mensaje enviado en el WS, y como los mensajes se envían cada segundo entre el cliente y el servidor, serían infinitas las conexiones a la BD. ¿Esto es así, correcto?

Supongo que la conexión a la BD tengo que ponerla fuera del método onMessage(), asumo que en el método onOpen(), con lo cual lograría que sólo existiera una única conexión a la BD, ¿correcto? Pero esto me acarrea dos problemas:

1. El sitio en el navegador funciona correcto con esta
   configuración, pero si recargo la página, truena la conexión del
   websocket indicando que no existe la conexión a la BD, y el navegador muestra un error 500
2. No me libro nunca de las múltiples peticiones a la BD: `$stmt->execute()`, y como la BD
   está en otro servidor, eso me hace suponer que el websocket no sirve
   de mucho cuando el servidor web está en un lado y el de BD en otro,
   ¿es así? Si lo es, ¿cuál sería la mejor forma de no afectar el rendimiento aquí?

Cualquier comentario que puedan dar para clarificar mis dudas y el funcionamiento de los WS me será de gran ayuda.

**EDICIÓN 1.**
Justo ahora acabo de separar la conexión BD del método onMessage() (lo saqué de ahí), y la puse dentro del constructor y dentro del método onOpen(), con lo cual logro que exista una única conexión a la BD durante la vida del WS. Ese problema queda arreglado. Queda el problema de que se realizarán infinitas peticiones a la BD:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT ...');
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
        // ...
    }
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Buenas, creo que utilizar una API rest podría ser una alternativa, ya que no utilizas el concepto de full-duplex que soporta los websocket, con referencia a la conexión, es correcto, desde mi punto de vista, el cerrar y abrir la conexión a la base de datos, ya que cada interacción genera un thread, también, cabe resaltar, que estas transfiriendo información, y al estar en servidores diferente, puede existir un poco de latencia entre cada consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El servidor de sockets solo debe recibir y enviar mensajes, dejando que el cliente sea el encargado del manejo de base de datos. Te sugiero revisar nuevamente el [tutorial de inicio](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) de *Ratchet*.

Además, el socket estará escuchando cualquier cambio en el servidor, por lo que no es necesario el intervalo.

```
let conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
conn.addEventListener('open', e => {
    console.log('Conexión establecida');
    // Solo si quieres enviar un mensaje a los usuarios conectados
    conn.send('Un usuario nuevo ha ingresado');

    // Este evento se asigna solo cuando se pudo establecer la conexión
    conn.addEventListener('message', e => {
        console.log('Mensaje recibido: ' + e.data);
    });
});
```

Cuando realizas modificaciones en la base de datos, supongamos que tienes un formulario con `id="datos"` y escuchas el evento submit:

```
document.querySelector('#datos').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // Preparas los datos para envío, incluyendo todos los campos del formulario
    let data = new FormData(this);
    // Envías al servidor (no Websocket) con petición AJAX
    fetch('http://localhost/ruta/archivo.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
    // Convertir la respuesta del servidor en JSON
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        // Si todo salió bien, el servidor ya actualizó la base de datos
        // Y te devolvió información en formato JSON
        // Hay que enviar al socket, para que otros usuarios reciban el mensaje
        // En tu ejemplo solo envías ID
        conn.send(response.id);
     });
});
```

El servidor de Websocket va a recibir el mensaje y lo va a enviar al resto de usuarios, quedando la función como la del tutorial:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        // Evitar enviar al autor del mensaje
        if ($from !== $client) {
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Si necesitas todos los datos completos y no solo ID, puedes modificar el envío:

```
conn.send(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Y modificar la recepción de mensajes:

```
conn.addEventListener('message', e => {
    let registro = JSON.parse(e.data);
    // Ya tienes los datos
    // Puedes usarlos para modificar el DOM o mostrar en consola
    console.log(registro.id, registro.fecha);
});
```

Por último, para que un usuario reciba solo los mensajes que le pertenecen, tal vez debas usar [sesiones en el servidor de Websocket](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions), pero eso ya es otro tema.